# Flutter google sign in issues

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm having problems with google sign in working in my app on debug mode(still have'nt published a release mode) after shifting to a new PC. It was working well initially.

For this new PC I have updated new SHA1 and SHA256 keys on Firebase console (There were 2 new sets of each  key generated) but I still get the error:

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Comment: is the project package name the same as your project on your other PC ?
Because this error happens when the package name, the sha1 or  the sha256 fingerprints are changed and need to be updated in the firebase console.

Comment: Hello, have you fixed this one?

Comment: @flutternewbiee Started a fresh project that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your `google-services.json` file in your Android project.

Comment: Also did that. Problem still persists